# Stack Overflow Teams API: How to get all questions or posts data?

Tags: support, api, automation

I am trying to build a database of all the posts and answers on my Stack Overflow team information. I am able to download all data in the "Settings" -> "Billing & Accounts" tab but I am looking for a way to automate the syncing through the API.

Answer (score 2):

The [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) has access to Teams data: the process to do so is described [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams). It's read-only, but that shouldn't be a problem for your purpose; [the lack of access to uploaded images](https://stackapps.com/q/8140/34061) might be.

Basically, you'll need a separate access token with `access_team|...` scope; note that the team URL is not just the Team's name but also includes `stackoverflow.com/c/` (experienced API users have fallen for this trap). This token needs to be passed as an HTTP header (`X-API-Access-Token`) instead of a regular parameter; otherwise, it works just like the 'normal' Stack Exchange API.

With the [/posts call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts) you can fetch all posts which have been changed since the last time you synced.